# Get Text From Element and Put it in Text as Value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve the following which includes:

1. Retrieve Data from an Element in JavaScript.

```html
<p id='returnText'>Text</p>
```

2. Set a from's Input Value to the retrieved text in step 1.

This is what i currently have and im really stuck :(

```js
function autoMagicallySubmit(){
 var html = document.getElementById("returnText").innerHTML;
 html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
 document.getElementById("sendText").value = html.text;
}
```

```html
<p id='returnText'>TEXT NEEDED TO BE TAKEN!</p>

<form name="myForm"action="Contact" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="sendText" id="sendText" value="">
</form>
```

But I keep retrieving "Undefined" in the texbox. I have php echoing the element which is under step 1.

Comment: `html = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ""); document.getElementById("sendText").value = html` This is enough.

Comment: i edited can you recheck! :) @Rajaprabhu

Comment: Whatever your edit may be, But my first comment will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("returnText").innerHTML;
```

Returns text and not an object that has an attribute "text".

You should just have `document.getElementById("sendText").value = html`

Comment: Thanks So Much! That helped, because i was reading another thread saying i needed to replace all the other HTML markup characters, and then do html.text; But Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` give you the text content (between `<p id='returnText'>` and (`</p>`) so is a string, not an object, and you need just the value

```js
function autoMagicallySubmit(){
 var txt = document.getElementById("returnText").innerHTML;
 txt.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
 document.getElementById("sendText").value = txt;
}
autoMagicallySubmit()
```

```html
<p id='returnText'>TEXT NEEDED TO BE TAKEN!</p>

<form name="myForm"action="Contact" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="sendText" id="sendText" value="">
</form>
```